# How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularjs if filter is false

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

Have some trouble with multiple filters. One filter works good, if add second filter ng-repeat get filters with operator AND, but I need take second filter if first is FALSE.

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
    {"id":1,"username":"", "age": "18"},
    {"id":8,"username":"betty", "age": ""},
    {"id":14,"username":"", "age": "18"},
    {"id":3,"username":"jumbo1", "age": ""},
  ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="user in filtered = (users | filter:{ 'username':'betty'}:true)">
      <span>{{ user.id }}</span>
    </div>  
  Users: {{users.length}}<br>
  Filtered Users: {{filtered.length}}    
  </div>
</body>
```

Multiple filters like, don't work:

```
filter:{ 'username':'betty'} || { 'age':'18'}
```

Finally need if first filter is FALSE take second filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you will need to create a simple filter function in controller. The usage could be something like this for example:

```
users | filter:userFilter({username: 'betty', age: 18}
```

Here is a demo:

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
    {"id":1,"username":"", "age": "18"},
    {"id":8,"username":"betty", "age": ""},
    {"id":14,"username":"", "age": "18"},
    {"id":3,"username":"jumbo1", "age": ""},
  ];
    
  $scope.userFilter = function(filter) {
    return function(user) {
      return user.username == filter.username || user.age == filter.age;
    };  
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="user in filtered = (users | filter:userFilter({username: 'betty', age: 18}))">
      <span>{{ user | json }}</span>
    </div>
    <pre>Users: {{users.length}}<br>Filtered Users: {{filtered.length}}</pre>    
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, have little question. I have multilevel JSON for example {"id":1,"username":"", "age": [{"years":18,"gender":"male"}]}. How filter by gender or years, try like age[0].years but nothing ...

Comment: I guess `return user.username == filter.username || user.age[0].years == filter.years`